# Is there a way to distinguish between 2XX and 304 responses in Gatling and show it in the report?

Tags: java, gatling

Is there a way to distinguish between 2XX and 304 responses in Gatling and show it in the report?

I added this to my http request following the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/check/), but I don't see a difference running it with our without it.

```
.check(
  status().saveAs("status")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with the free version.

This chart is available in the [Enterprise version](https://gatling.io/enterprise/) though.

[image]